# Superfish - how to integrate main & user menu together

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I am using superfish module to decorate the menu system but found one issue. i need to show my "main menu" & "user menu" blocks on header region. so that if user is logged in, they can see all the main menu along with "user menu" otherwise only they can see the "main menu" items such as [home, Games, Blog]. Please suggest some alternative if this approach is not recommended or proper.

[image]

Drupal version - 7.23
Bartik 7.23
Superfish module 7.x-1.9

Comment: Why don't you add them manually to main menu?

Answer (score 0):

Go to main menu and add ***My account*** with path `user` and add ***Log out*** with path `user/logout`

SO that links will appear as you expected

Comment: then what about this "if user is logged in, they can see all the main menu along with "user menu" otherwise only they can see the "main menu" items such as [home, Games, Blog]"

Comment: @NarendraSingh Is that menu from block?